# Activity date for automated mailings

Tags: civimail

For an automated emailing,  eg for event registration, why is the Activity date shown as the date the email was set up ('Scheduled'), not the date the automated emailing took place.   For example, we have event participants who registered for an event on 23 April receiving a set of post registration emails, with Activities all dated April 4th, long before they had even registered.  Can this be changed as part of configuration.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is down to the fact that your using the mailing jobs as part of your scheduled reminders and this is the reason the wrong date shows up. The mailing job will have the date of the 4th of april and thefore the activities all show that date. p.s. This is Parvez @ Veda hence I know the setup!